# Inserting data into a junction table entity framework

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables in my database, "Customer" and "Integration" with a junction table in between them. The Customer gets added and saved and the Integration table is pre-populated with integration flows which the customer must choose to be assigned to their ID. The data entities look as follows:

[image: Entities]

The code to add customers looks like:

```
 public JsonResult RegisterUser(Courier courier, Customer customer, Station station, List<Integration> integration, IntegrationCapability intCapabilities, List<Question> question, List<SysIntClient> sysintClient)
    {
        string returnMessage = "";
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null);

        customer.ExpectedGoLive = dt;

        OnbardingDBEntities nt = new OnbardingDBEntities();
        try
        {

            nt.Customers.Add(customer);
            nt.SaveChanges();

            int cust_ID = 0;
            if (customer.CustName != null)
            {
                cust_ID = getCustomerID(customer.CustName);
            }
            else
            {
                cust_ID = 0;
            }
```

Now what I am trying to do is add a record to the junction table between Integration and Customer. The customer gets added, then I get the IDs from a selection made by the customer and want to add those IDs to a junction table between Customer and Integration. What I have so far is:

```
Integration integration_flow = null;
            foreach (Integration i in integration)
            {
                integration_flow = new Integration();

                integration_flow.IntID = i.IntID;
                integration_flow.SI_ID = i.SI_ID;
                integration_flow.IntegrationFlow = i.IntegrationFlow;

                integration_flow.Customers.Add(customer);
                customer.Integrations.Add(integration_flow);
                nt.SaveChanges(); 

            }
```

This doesn't seem to be working because I don't want to add to the Integration table and I've already saved to the Customer table. How else can I independently access the junction table from the entity framework and add to it.

EDIT:

The following is an image from the DB to show the db structure of the junction table:

[image: Junction table]

My understanding is that:

```
 integration_flow.Customers.Add(customer);
                customer.Integrations.Add(integration_flow);
                nt.SaveChanges();
```

would add to the integration and customer table respectively

Or would it not?

Comment: Not related, but as a side note, you do not need `cust_ID = getCustomerID(customer.CustName);` - the `ID` property of your `customer` object is populated with its value when you call `.SaveChanges()`

Comment: What is the 'junction' table, and what are its properties? (is that table you would need to add records to)

Comment: I have edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: Then just create new instances of `Integration_Customer` for each `Integration`, and set its properties (there should be a property for the `CustomerID` and the `IntegrationID` as well as the PK). Then add to the context and save at the end of the loop. (and just use `customer.ExpectedGoLive = DateTime.Now; - your 2 preceding lines of code are pointless)